# Oracle Sql Developer - user interface (newbie)

Tags: sqldeveloper

I’m new to Oracle Sql Developer, 
I’m just searching for some explanatory guide or good video tutorial to explain basic principles of its interface,
for example

what is the difference between **Worksheet** and **Query Builder** (tab)?

**Run Script** vs. **Run Statement**? (button)

and finally **Script Output** vs. **Query Result**? (tab)

thank you

Comment: Run script will run all of it; Run statement a single statement. Script output is just pure text while query result will give you some bling. At least if I remember it correctly. Instead of looking for a guide just try it out.

Comment: SQLDeverloper is a finicky tool, so I do recommend finding alternatives if at all possible. Get used to highlighting the code you want to run and executing it with Ctrl Enter, rather than hitting F5. Also, remember, if you update a record, you must commit your changes before they become permanent.